# how to get object using callback data in jquery?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

i am using `jquery` to get values from database via `servlet`. callback function in my script gives me raw information from database.how can i append these values to select option in `jsp`.

**here is my Retrive_country servlet code:**

```
String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM state WHERE country_ref="+countryref+"                      
PreparedStatement pst1 = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql1);
ResultSet j = pst1.executeQuery();

while (j.next()) {
    state_id = j.getString(1);
    state = j.getString(2);
    country_ref = j.getString(3);
    location.setState(state);
    location.setState_id(state_id);
    location.setcountry_ref(country_ref);
    pw.println(state_id);
    pw.println(state);
    pw.println(country_ref);
}
```

**here is my script:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#country_id").change(function() {
      var xyz = $("option:selected").val();
      alert(xyz)
      $.get("../Retrive_country?countryREF="+xyz",
        {countryREF : xyz }, 
            function(data){
              console.log(data);
                alert("Data: " + data);
            });

   });
});
</script>
```

**here is my jsp:**

```
<div class="span2 clear">
<select name="country_id" id="country_id">
<option>-select-</option>


<option id="blabbb">1</option>
<option id="blabbb">2</option>
<option id="blabbb">3</option>

</select></div>

<div class="span2 clear">
<select name="state_ref" id="state_ref">
<option ></option>
</select></div>
```

**here is my output in console:**

[image]

all the strings are state values and integers are stateid.

i want them to be used separately in jsp.

Comment: Do you have some sample backend response?

Comment: Could you send your response as json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use a backend JSON encoder. But this manual encode should work, too:

Backend code:

```
pw.println("[");
while (j.next()) {
    state_id = j.getString(1);
    state = j.getString(2);
    country_ref = j.getString(3);
    pw.println("{stateId: " + state_id + ", stateName: \"" + state +"\"},");
}
pw.println("]");
```

(I'm assuming your state_id is integer)

Client code:

```
$("#country_id").change(function() {
   var xyz = $("option:selected").val();
   $.get("../Retrive_country?stateadd_1=none", {countryREF : xyz }, function(data){
       var states = eval(data);
       $('#state_ref').empty();
       $.each(states, function(index, state){
            $("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", state.stateId).text(state.stateName)
                .appendTo('#state_ref');
       });           
   }, 'text');
});
```

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: it's not working, alert(state.stateName); gives output as "undefined"

Comment: @Edgar: change 'text' to 'json' then you dont have to eval(data)

Comment: @alex. Hi, Unfortunately not, as the server didn't do a real JSON encode but a manual one. For example, trailing commas would fail with datatype `json`, which is this case. Eval is more permissive.

Comment: @Edgar: its not working this time its not even throwing an alert.

Comment: @Edgar:can you please explain me why did u add \ in pw.println("{stateId: " + state_id + ", stateName: \"" + state +"\"},");

Comment: It's because we're returning an array of objects in JSON format. JSON means JavaScript Object Notation, easily parseable in JS. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can send data as json. You can do this:

```
var Myselect = $('#state_ref');
$.getJSON("../Retrive_country?stateadd_1=none",
    {countryREF : xyz } ,function(data){
     $.each(data, function(key, value) {   
     Myselect
     .append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value",key)
     .text(value)); 
  });//end each
 });//end get
```

If not in json format, can you show what your data looks like?

Comment: this is not working,i have all the information retrieved in callback "data" what i want is just how to separate data coming from servlet.i have three strings state,state_id,country_ref coming from servlet but they are all together coming in to call back function how can i again separate them so that i can use them in my jsp.

Comment: When you do console.log(data), what do you see? If its json then usually data.state, data.state_id, data.country_ref will do.

Comment: If you can show me the result of console.log(data), I can show you how to extract the values. Just show me the  format of the data coming out.

Comment: it shows 1st values in order of state_id,state,country_ref and then sencond value and so on..

Comment: are values comma separated? what about the rows, are they separated as well? Could you show a sample...?

Comment: i have pasted a screen shot of my console in my que please do refer.thank you.

Comment: Why dont you format your data on the servlet side as json as @Edgar has suggested. It will make your life easier...

Comment: i am sorry but i have very little knowledge about JSON if its possible can you make it for me.thank you.

Comment: But @Edgar pretty much did it for you. Whats the problem there?

Comment: Great, it's simple as that ;)

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT USE `+`** in the `PreparedStatement` query!!

It's intended for using things like

```
String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM state WHERE country_ref=?"
PreparedStatement pst1 = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql1)
pst1.setInteger(0,country_ref);
ResultSet j = pst1.executeQuery();
```

It is because of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). As described, the easiest way to escape that injection type is using prepared statements **properly**. Please read more about using `PreparedStatement`

Comment: This is a true statement, however this is not an answer to the question.